# Can I split item stacks evenly using a trackpad?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.5, a new feature was added: when placing a stack of items in the workbench, if you hold both the right and left mouse buttons down and drag, the stack of items will be split evenly across all the squares you drag them over, simplifying the process of crafting a large number of identical items.

But I play Minecraft on a Mac using the trackpad...right-click is performed by pressing with two fingers, left click with one. No gesture for simultaneous right and left click exists.

Is there a way to assign this new feature to, say, shift + click-and-drag instead of right-and-left-click-and-drag so it can be used with a Mac trackpad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use both buttons; the function you describe is just left-click drag.

- Left-click dragging will split the held stack evenly across all slots dragged over. (If the destination already contains some of the item, then equal counts will be *added* to the existing counts, so the result will not be even.)
- Right-click dragging will put 1 item in each slot dragged over.